# Oracle collection in where clause

Tags: oracle, collections

I am using collection in a oracle code block because there is no table variable(like in MS SQL Server).

```
DECLARE
    TYPE I_NAME IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(512);     
    I_ITEMNAME      I_NAME := I_NAME(); 
BEGIN
```

I am using "BULK COLLECT INTO I_ITEMNAME" to fill collection. 
I want to use this collection in WHERE clause in a SELECT query but not able to find method to do it. Currently i and using FOR loop and getting item one by one.
How can i use collection directly in WHERE clause somethin like

> SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE COL IN I_ITEMNAME?

Thank you,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use a locally declared collection in an SQL clause:

```
declare
    type i_name is table of nvarchar2(512);
    i_itemname i_name := i_name();
    c number;
begin
    select distinct owner bulk collect into i_itemname from all_objects;
    dbms_output.put_line(i_itemname.count);
    select count(*) into c
    from all_tables
    where owner in (select * from table(i_itemname));
    dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
/

    where owner in (select * from table(i_itemname));
                                        *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 41:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 10, column 35:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But you can if it's declared at schema level, essentially so that SQL knows about the type, not just PL/SQL:

```
create type i_name is table of nvarchar2(512);
/

Type created.

declare
    i_itemname i_name := i_name();      
    c number;
begin 
    select distinct owner bulk collect into i_itemname from all_objects;
    dbms_output.put_line(i_itemname.count);
    select count(*) into c from all_tables
    where owner in (select * from table(i_itemname));
    dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
/

No errors.
18
128

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can also join the `table` construct rather than use a subquery:

```
...
    select count(*) into c
    from table(i_itemname) t
    join all_tables at on at.owner = t.column_value;
...
```

I'm not quite clear what you're dong though. (If you aren't using the collection for anything else, you'd be better off just joining the raw data, but I assume the collection is there for a reason).

---

As @haki mentioned in comments, you can also do:

```
...
    select count(*) into c
    from all_tables
    where owner member of (i_itemname);
...
```

... as long as `i_name` and the column you're comparing with [are the same type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions006.htm#sthref1966). In my example it finds zero rows because I'm trying to compare `nvarchar2` with `varchar2`, but would find a match if redefined `i_name` as `varchar2(512)`. In your case presumably `tab.col` is `nvarchar2` anyway.

Comment: +1 I think you can also use it like this `select count(*) from all_tables where owner member of (i_itemname)`.

Comment: @haki - nice, I don't think I've ever used that. For my example it finds no matches [because the type doesn't match](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions006.htm#sthref1966) - I have `i_type` as `nvarchar2` but `owner` is `varchar2`, but it's neat if `i_type` is redefined to match. (I've added that to my answer, but if you post your own answer with that I'll remove it; not trying to take credit!)

Comment: this is a perfect explanation , for better performance - if your collection size is going to be huge - it is better to have the type indexed - for ex -   create type i_name    is table of number index by PLS_INTEGER;