# Optimizing an Oracle SQL query which uses IN clause extensively

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I maintain an application where I am trying to optimize an Oracle SQL query wherein multiple IN clauses are used. This query is now a blocker as it hogs nearly 3 minutes of execution time and affects application performance severely.The query is called from Java code(JDBC) and looks like this :

```
Select disctinct col1,col2,col3,.. colN from Table1
where 1=1 and not(col1 in (idsetone1,idsetone2,... idsetoneN)) or
(col1 in(idsettwo1,idsettwo2,...idsettwoN))....
(col1 in(idsetN1,idsetN2,...idsetNN))
```

The ID sets are retrieved from a different schema and therefore a JOIN between column1 of table 1 and ID sets is not possible. ID sets have grown over time with use of the application and currently they number more than 10,000 records.

How can I start with optimizing this query ?

Comment: Why are you using multiple `in` clauses?  They are all on the same column.  Combine the lists into a single list.

Comment: If you use `NOT IN` and `OR` will take time, hence try to avoid as Gordon Linoff said

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oracle accepts up to 1000 elements in list.

Comment: What do you really mean by "a different schema"?  Obviously it *is* possible to join tables from different schemas: `from schema1.table1 join schema2.tabl2...`

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061

Comment: additionally `1=1` condition is handy for creating dynamic sql, but might confuse the optimizier. Had it at least one time, that indexes weren't used properly...

Comment: Are you selecting the IDs from one JDBC connection and using them in another, and the two DBs cant be connected together via a link? If so have you looked at using an array to pass all of the values in one go? ([This sort of thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26746950/266304)).

Answer (score 2):

I really doupt about "The ID sets are retrieved from a different schema and therefore a JOIN between column1 of table 1 and ID sets is not possible." Of course you can join the tables, provided you got select privileges on it.

Anyway, let's assume it is not possible due to whatever reason. One solution could be to insert all entries first into a Nested Table and the use this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

Select disctinct col1,col2,col3,.. colN from Table1
where 1=1 
   and not (col1 NOT MEMBER OF (NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE(idsetone1,idsetone2,... idsetoneN)) 
      OR
      (col1 MEMBER OF NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE(idsettwo1,idsettwo2,...idsettwoN))
```

Regarding the max. number of elements [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00504) says: *Because a nested table does not have a declared size, you can put **as many elements** in the constructor **as necessary**.*

I don't know how serious you can take this statement.

Comment: You should prepare the Statement with a Bind-variable MEMBER OF :1 and directly construct the nested Table with JDBC and put it in there - than it will be streamed to the database and you don't have to build/parse gigantig SELECT-Strings. It will be blazing fast!

Comment: FYI - you misspelled `DISTINCT`, but I see that's from the OP

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the items into one temporary table and to an explicit join:

```
Select your cols
from Table1
left join table_with_items 
 on table_with_items.id = Table1.col1
where table_with_items.id is null;
```

Also that `distinct` suggest a problem in your business logic or in the architecture of application. Why do you have duplicate ids? You should get rid of that distinct.

Comment: Might be better in Oracle to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` over the outer join non-matched query.