# Execute a Select inside a loop PL/SQL and return cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is probably a simple question for who knows PL/SQL.
I have a stored procedure who takes an array of varchar in input:

```
TYPE MULTI is table of VARCHAR(15) index by BINARY_INTEGER;


PROCEDURE MYPROC(
    SINGLE                                IN     MULTI,
    P_RESULT                              OUT    MY_PCK.MYCURSOR,
    P_SOMETHING                           OUT    VARCHAR2,
);
```

The cursor works because i have tested it in other cases but this is the first with an array parameter.

I have a problem with the body, how can i assign each value i get from the select to the cursor?

```
 BEGIN 
  FOR i IN SINGLE.first .. SINGLE.last
  LOOP
  --BEGIN OPEN P_RESULT FOR this --this on left gives me error
                                SELECT MT.DESCR INTO P_SOMETHING
                                FROM MYTABLE1 MT
                                WHERE MT.IDS = SINGLE(i)
                                AND and rownum < 2;
--dbms_output.put_line(SINGLE(i)); --if i use this instead of select i get the values i send to this procedure.
  END LOOP;
```

i tried also:

```
SELECT MT.DESCR INTO P_RESULT but gives error
```

What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement. If i use an into clause like: MT.DESCR INTO P_SOMETHING where P_SOMETHING is a varchar2 output, i get: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. I really don't know how to solve this...

Comment: For quickly solve try add this in WHERE clause: and rownum < 2

Comment: What is the definition of `MY_PCK.MYCURSOR`; and which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @AlexPoole for MYCURSOR:  type MYCURSOR IS REF CURSOR; for Oracle: 11g Express Edition

Comment: @I3rutt I tried that, the procedure doesnt' give errors but it doesnt' give a result in P_SOMETHING. (i.e. i can't see it in output variables window).

Comment: @Mark Fallow show your last version of code

Comment: That's a shame, in 12c you can use a PL/SQL-declared type like `MULTI` in a SQL query, but in 11g you still can't. So I don't think you can do this without resorting to SQL-level types.

Comment: @AlexPoole Can you explain a bit the SQL-level types?

Comment: @I3rutt I'll edited my question for that. Thanks

Comment: If you can't find a way to solve this, a good guide will be really appreciated. I didn't find something useful for this, i think very common, case.

Comment: @MarkFallow - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16185941/266304); not exactly the same but same distinction between PL/SQL and SQL collection types. (In 12c you can use the PL/SQL collection int he `TABLE(...)` version, but still not the `MEMBER OF` version).

Comment: @Mark Fallow I think you need to debug your procedure and watch the value of P_SOMETHING on every iteration steps

Comment: I'll debug it after dinner and i let you :D keep an hope to find a solution here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your PL/SQL collection type in a SQL statement in 11g. You could create a SQL collection type, or find one you already have access to (which has a suitable string length) and use that to at least verify the mechanism.

For instance, this uses a local variable of type `SYS.HSBLKNAMLST`, which is defined as a `table of varchar2(30)`, more than enough to match your own PL/SQL type's string length. That variable is populated from your passed-in PL/SQL type, and that is then used in a query to open the cursor:

```
PROCEDURE MYPROC(
  SINGLE                                IN     MULTI,
  P_RESULT                              OUT    MY_PCK.MYCURSOR
) IS
  LOCAL_COLL SYS.HSBLKNAMLST := SYS.HSBLKNAMLST();
BEGIN 
  FOR i IN SINGLE.first .. SINGLE.last
  LOOP
    LOCAL_COLL.extend();
    LOCAL_COLL(LOCAL_COLL.last) := SINGLE(i);
  END LOOP;

  OPEN P_RESULT FOR
    SELECT MT.DESCR
    FROM MYTABLE1 MT
    LEFT JOIN TABLE(LOCAL_COLL) LC
    ON LC.COLUMN_VALUE = MT.IDS
    WHERE LC.COLUMN_VALUE IS NULL;

END;
```

I'm a bit confused about the query you showed in your loop though; you seem to be attempting to re-open the cursor for each element of the array, though maybe you were trying to append the result of the query for each element to the same cursor - thought the `!=` would mean that all rows would be included at some point. I've guess that you're trying to get all records with `IDS` values that are not in the array. If you actually want all that are then that would be:

```
  OPEN P_RESULT FOR
    SELECT MT.DESCR
    FROM TABLE(LOCAL_COLL) LC
    JOIN MYTABLE1 MT
    ON MT.IDS = LC.COLUMN_VALUE;
```

---

You can see which built-in types are available to you by querying the data dictionary, e.g:

```
select owner, type_name, coll_type, elem_type_name, length
from all_coll_types
where elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2'
and coll_type = 'TABLE'
and owner = 'SYS'
order by length;
```

It would be preferable to create your own SQL type if you're able to.

Comment: The != was a mistake (testing...), sorry for that. I'll try what you wrote.