# How to pass arguments in IN clause of select statement as parameter having multiple values?

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, sqlplus

Iam writing a script in unix where where iam trying to implement the following

1) Connect to a database
2) run a select query and fetch the results in a file for validation

Now i have written the following

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./database.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 . $file

  echo "User Id       = " ${userName}
  echo "user password = " ${password}
  echo "schema  = " ${schema}

  sqlplus -S ${userName}/${password}@${schema}
  set feedback off trimspool on 
spool workflow_details.txt;
SELECT WORKFLOW_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, (END_TIME-START_TIME)*24*60 as TIME_TAKEN
 FROM schema1.table1
 WHERE WORKFLOW_NAME IN ('argument1,argument2,argument3,argument4')
 AND WORKFLOW_RUN_ID IN (SELECT MAX(WORKFLOW_RUN_ID) FROM schema2.table3
 WHERE WORKFLOW_NAME IN ('argument1'));
spool off;
exit;

else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

---

The requirement is the value iam using in In clause i.e( argument1,argument2....etc.) is present in a file and the script should be modified such that the arguments will be fetched and placed in In clause through comma separation. The number of arguments is dynamic . How to modify the code.

In short I need to fetch the arguments for IN clause at run time from a file having the argument details . The file will look like having a single column consisting of arguments.

Comment: Use a collection and then pass the collection to `IN` clause. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185277/oracle-collection-in-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments you need to use `Collection` to fulfill your requirement. See below demo and explanation inline.

**In `PLSQL`**

```
-- Declare a Nested table of type Number. You can declare it of type of your argument1,argument2..

    Create or replace type var is table of number;
    /

    DECLARE
        v_var   var := var ();
        v_num number;
    BEGIN
        --Fetching rows to collection
        SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO
            v_var
        FROM (
            SELECT 1 FROM dual
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 FROM dual
        );

        --Printing values of collection 
        FOR rec IN 1..v_var.count LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(v_var(rec) );
        END LOOP;

        --Using in Where clause.       
        Select count(1)
        into v_num
        from dual where 1 Member of v_var; --<-- this is how you pass the collection of number in `IN` clause.

        dbms_output.put_line(v_num );
    END;
```

In your case: **UNIX script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#read from file and prepare the "in clause" --<--Put a loop to read through the file
in_clause=argument1,argument2  #--Prepare your `in_clause`


file="./database.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 . $file

  echo "User Id       = " ${userName}
  echo "user password = " ${password}
  echo "schema  = " ${schema}

  sqlplus -S ${userName}/${password}@${schema}
  set feedback off trimspool on 
  spool workflow_details.txt;

   SELECT workflow_name,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      ( end_time - start_time ) * 24 * 60 AS time_taken
    FROM schema1.table1
    WHERE workflow_name IN ($in_clause )      #<--Use in clause
          AND   workflow_run_id IN (SELECT MAX(workflow_run_id) FROM schema2.table3 WHERE workflow_name IN ( 'argument1' )
    );

spool off;
exit; 
else 
echo "$file not found." 
fi
```

PS: Not tested