# Input parameters in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Tell me how to solve such a case:

There is a predicate in the stored procedure that searches for *input_param* by the input parameter:

```
procedure tst (input_param in varchar2)
is
    select
        so_much_columns
    from
        so_much_tables
    where
        value in (input_param);
end tst;
```

When calling this procedure, I need to pass two or much parameters:

```
call tst.tst (input_param => 'Tst1, Tst2');
```

It naturally doesn't work

Are there any solutions?

Comment: You need to pass it as a `collection`. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185277/oracle-collection-in-where-clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle collection in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185277/oracle-collection-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename from emp where deptno in (10, 20) order by deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 MILLER
        10 CLARK
        10 KING
        20 FORD
        20 ADAMS
        20 JONES
        20 SMITH
        20 SCOTT

8 rows selected.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (input_param in varchar2) as
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*) into l_cnt
  5    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  6    where d.deptno in (select regexp_substr(input_param, '[^,]+', 1, level)
  7                       from dual
  8                       connect by level <= regexp_count(input_param, ',') + 1
  9                      );
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Count = ' || l_cnt);
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('10, 20');
Count = 8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: @Littlefoot, Thnx for your reply, this is what I need
Can you tell me, what if there are two such variables?

Comment: I got this option, but performance drops a lot
  
  where ...
  and d.deptnoTst in (select regexp_substr(input_param2, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                     from dual
                     connect by level <= regexp_count(input_param2, ',') + 1;
  dbms_output.put_line('Count = ' || l_cnt);
end;
/

Comment: You're welcome. What if there are two variables? Huh, as you say, performance suffers with *one* variable. It'll suffer even more with two of them. Solution? Don't pass such a data. If you stored values into a table, index it and use as JOIN with your other table, it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have variadic arguments. You can instead create a global array/list type and pass it instead to your procedure. To select data from a table using your array use `member of`.

Be careful with `member of`, if a field is number your array should also be of number datatype, otherwise you will get nothing.

Your **array/list**:

```
create or replace type test_array as table of varchar2(32767);
```

And the **procedure**:

```
procedure run(args test_array) is
  results test_array;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(args.count);
  dbms_output.put_line(args(1));
  dbms_output.put_line(args(2));
  dbms_output.put_line(args(3));

  select t.name
    bulk collect
    into results
    from test_rows t
   where t.name member of args;

  dbms_output.put_line(results.count);
end;
```

**Here is how you can test:**

*Test table:*

```
create table TEST_ROWS
(
  name VARCHAR2(1)
)
tablespace SYSTEM
  pctfree 10
  pctused 40
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

*Test rows:*

```
prompt Importing table TEST_ROWS...
set feedback off
set define off
insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('A');

insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('B');

insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('C');

insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('D');

insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('E');

insert into TEST_ROWS (NAME)
values ('F');

prompt Done.
```

*Calling procedure:*

```
procedure test_run is
  v_array test_array := test_array();
begin
  v_array.extend(3);
  v_array(1) := 'A';
  v_array(2) := 'B';
  v_array(3) := 'C';

  run(v_array);
end;
```

*Will output:*

```
3
A
B
C
3
```